How to tighten security screw with H pattern on bike seat?
My bike seat has a bolt connecting it to the seatpost, which has come loose. The bolt on the underside of the seat is standard and can be turned with a hex wrench, but it's connected to what I believe is a security screw (pictured below) which needs to be held in place or turned in the opposite direction: otherwise the bolt and the security screw spin freely together. The security screw isn't the typical security torx: it has a very shallow H shaped indent in it instead. It's shallow enough that I wonder if it could even hold the screw in place while the bolt turns, but I don't see anything else to grip onto since the security screw is perfectly round. Searching for bike H screws returns derailleur H limit screws, so it's been hard to find anything on this.
Is this a standard type of security screw I can buy a tool for? The seat is from Selle Royal, and the seatpost is from an Azor (Amsterdam-based company) bike.


I suspect this is supposed to be a stud, which has come loose from its mount and the H is just a logo?  Its definitely part of the seatpost not the saddle itself.

That looks like the end of the bolt . Is there no access to the bolt head from below the seat and post head.

It turns with the bolt because it IS the bolt. You are right Warren. I am an idiot.

You are looking at the end of the bolt. If you look under the post there should be access to a regular hex head.
The "H" may be an indicator (Hardened ?) for the grade of the bolt or a manufacturer mark.
The torque rating for a seat post bolt generally will be in the order of 10-15 Nm. I.e quite a lot but not too much if using a wrist-o-meter.
